# App to tell me what to make for dinner every day

Tags: android

Here's the thing: I'm not a bad cook. I am just really indecisive. As a result, here's what I'm looking for.

1. I want an Android app
2. It will pick recipes for me to make every day

   - If I can only get recipes every other day or something (pick my recipe frequency) that would be even better.
3. Ideally, it will also include a shopping list feature
4. Even better if it has a web app.
5. If it has options to add recipes to the rotation if I liked them, that would be great, or the option to say "I never want to see this recipe again."
6. Ideally, it will not have any ads. I'm willing to pay a small amount ($3-5 a month) for a service that has the right feature set.

Comment: Really? You want something to tell you to go shopping for ingredients? As opposed to something where you tell it what ingredients you have at home& recommends from those? Sounds like you are going to end up with a lot of left over ingredients :-/

Comment: @Mawg, obviously I'm not going to buy the stuff if I already have it--but I want something that will make a shopping list for me (I'm not the type to have a ton of non-standard ingredients on hand constantly)

Comment: Still not sure how it works. 1) it chooses a random meal 2) it prints a list of ingredients 3) you look at your cupboard and strike off those which you already have 4) you go shopping for the others?  Sorry if I sound dumb, it's 1am. I would like to help; just trying to grok the requirements. And couldn't you just open a cook book at a random page?

Comment: http://www.reciperoulette.tv

Answer (score 1):

## Update:

Now you can directly use Google Now's [culinary inspiration](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/new-google-cooking-cards-spotted-google-now/187053/)

[image: Culinary inspiration]

Maybe you can ask Google Assistant to remind you every evening

---

If you use Facebook messenger then there are several chatbots for dinner suggestions. You just need to subscribe and they'll send you proposals everyday

- [Dinner Ideas](https://www.facebook.com/DinnerIdeasBot/)
- [Food Network](http://www.foodnetwork.com/site/apps/chatbot)
- [Whole Foods](https://www.facebook.com/WholeFoods/?ref=br_rs)

Some reviews and suggestions for them

- [Best Bots for Recipes and Food Recommendations](http://www.whatbot.com/?p=365)
- [Thinking What to Cook Again? Ask Dinner Ideas Bot](https://whatarechatbots.com/thinking-what-to-cook-again-ask-dinner-ideas-bot-c059cb9c7430)
- [Whole Foods just launched a Messenger chatbot for finding recipes with emojis](https://venturebeat.com/2016/07/12/whole-foods-just-launched-a-messenger-chatbot-for-finding-recipes-with-emojis/?utm_source=socialtimes&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_campaign=dailynewsletter20160713)
- [Whole Foods guide](https://www.topbots.com/project/whole-foods-recipe-bot-guide/)
- [Food Network Launches Bot for Messenger](http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20161118005355/en/Food-Network-Launches-Bot-Messenger)
- [10 Best Chatbot Apps powered by AI](https://masterofcode.com/blog/10-best-chatbot-ai-apps)

You can find more bots with these tools

- https://chatbottle.co/bots/messenger?q=dinner
- https://www.topbots.com/?s=dinner
- https://botlist.co/search?query=dinner

There you can also find chatbots for other platforms like Alexa

In case you want some suggestion based on what's remaining in the refrigerator you may want to try these

- http://myfridgefood.com/
- http://www.foodwise.com.au/recipe-room/our-recipe-finder/
- https://realfood.tesco.com/recipes/collections/leftovers.html
- https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/collection/leftovers
- ...